# Can't understand Contextual Filter + Relationship Result in View

Tags: 8, views

**Drupal 8**

**Goal**
When viewing a content type Story, I want a view to show other Story nodes that **do not** have the same taxonomy term as the Story that is being viewed. To achieve this I created a view with:

- Contextual Filter `Content ID, Provide default value, Raw value from URL, Path component 2, More - Exclude`  so as to not have the viewed Story show up on the view
- `Relationship` from the Taxonomy Term ID referenced by a field in Story content type
- Contextual Filter `Term ID` that uses previous relationship: `Provide default value, Taxonomy term ID from URL, Load default filter from term page, Load default filter from node page, Limit terms by vocabulary, More - Exclude`

And it works, **sort of**. When accessing a Story that has at least one **taxonomy term** associated to it, the view shows other stories that don't have the same taxonomy term. But, when viewing a story that has **no taxonomy term** associated to it, the view shows nothing.

Am I wrong to think that the view should be showing all the results?